# get latest state from callback registered in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

A component like below

```
function Comp(){
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    someService.on('event', ()=>{
      // how to get the latest a?
      console.log(a);
    })
  }, []);

  return (<button onClick={()=>{setA(a+1); someService.emit('event');}}>XXX</button>)
}
```

I hope every time i click the button, i can get the console with the latest state, the way i know is useRef:

```
const aRef = useRef(a);
useEffect(()=>{
  aRef.current = a;
}, a);
```

then console `aRef.current` can reach the latest value, but is there a way better?

Comment: What is your aim here? If you just want to access the value of `a` you can do that anywhere, anytime as it's a react state? Don't see why you'd need a Ref

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by the latest a. But if you want to skip the initial render of useEffect and to get the value afterwards. You can use that hook:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useFirstRender() {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    firstRender.current = false;
  }, []);

  return firstRender.current;
}
```

In that case:

```
function Comp(){
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const firstRender = useFirstRender();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!firstRender){
    someService.on('event', ()=>{
      // how to get the latest a?
      console.log(a);
    })
   }
  }, []);

  return (<button onClick={()=>{setA(a+1); someService.emit('event');}}>XXX</button>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another useEffect that tracks changes to "'a" state

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(a)
}, [a])
```

Or
Move the setA inside the service event.
You cannot directly console log the latest state after setting state as it will get set after you console log it, so you get stale data. That is why you need to track new state with another varoable and use it as a reference

```
function Comp(){
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    someService.on('event', ()=>{
       Const myNewA = a+1;
      setA(myNewA); 
      console.log(myNewA);
    })
  }, []);

  return (<button onClick{someService.emit('event');}}>XXX</button>)
}
```